# How to hide gridview in android

Tags: android

I have an application with One `Activity` and a `ListView` and `GridView` and two `Buttons`. When I display a `GridView` using button , it is displayed correctly , But when I click on `ListView` button to display it. It overlaps the `Gridview` control.

How can I handle this ? by hiding the `GridView` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just try this below code hide listview and show gridview:

```
gridshowbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          yourlistview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          yourgridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
});
```

if the click listview button try this below code:

```
listshowbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          yourlistview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          yourgridview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
});
```